`cabal install` failed with complaining a non-required file doesn't exist. How to get more detailed information?
I substantially changed a project and removed unused files. Now I cannot install with
"Error: [Cabal-4765] xx.hs doesn't exist".
The file xx.hs does not exist in the project and is not used in any of the files and I have no memory where it ever existed.
I there a way to get more detailed information why the file is required and where it should be located?
How to proceed with installing? Building works fine, run starts ok.

If you do cabal sdist --list-only, is that missing any *.hs files? Also, if you do cabal clean, does cabal build continue to work after that?

Can you share the file name? Or is it literally xx.hs?

@Noughtmare - The filename was like SomeThingLong.hs, a file I created and later deleted from the project (and do not remember in which directory). Obviously, the project is contais a large number of files etc. and is way to big to share; and I fear, that trying to pare it down, the error will vanish.

@Noughtmare - Thank you for the suggestion: cabal sdist --list-only does indeed not list all the *.hs files. Missing are the files in the app directory which are listed in the executables and files in the test-suite. After cabal clean build works and `cabal install still gives the error. Any other idea, where the request may originate?

The request for the xx.hs file was in a test-suite in a package which was loaded. The package produced an test-suite which required the xx.hs file. Once this test-suite fixed (i.e. replace the file with an existing one), the package which imported it, did install.
Given that one imports typically many packages, the error message should include at least the name of the package, in which the file was requested - otherwise the chase may be long.
I also wonder why one of the   test-suites in an imported package is blocking the installation; I do not see, how the files in the test-suite would be necessary for the executable of this package.

Now that you know what the issue was, can you make a small reproducer? I would like to help improve the error message, but I still don't really understand what the issue is from your description.

i will try; I guess I can reconstruct it from my files.
